# How to dump YUV in Android Native OMXCodec (S3 & Note 3)

Tags: android, dump, yuv, android-mediacodec, stagefright

i have followed below method to access `YUV` buffer. It works in few phones. But in S3 and Note 3 I'm getting problem. any reason ? Please help me.

```
sp<GraphicBuffer> mCurrGraphicBuffer;

void *vaddr;

mCurrGraphicBuffer = mVideoBuffer->graphicBuffer();

mCurrGraphicBuffer->lock(GRALLOC_USAGE_SW_READ_OFTEN, &vaddr);
```

I tried to google, but nothing helped me.

Comment: This YUV comes from the camera and you want to change it before it gets into the HW encoder, is that right?

Comment: Hi Alex,I receive H264 Streams from network and after JB, i'll provide these streams to OMXCodec. Rendering is Fine. But i need to capture some Key frames to JPG. So i wrote this code to that. In most of the handsets its working fine. But in Note3 and S3 I'm facing this problem.

Comment: Aha, so you set up your stagefright to render the output on surface. On some Samsung devices, you will not have access to the YUV frame in this case. You can run a separate decoder to receive YUV. If you really need key frames only, you can run this decoder once in a while.

Comment: Ok. I will try to create decoder for this case. I'll update you.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of `lock` to provide a mapped virtual address is dependent on the vendor's internal implementation in `gralloc`.

One potential cause for your issue could be that the `GraphicBuffer` **may not** have been created with `usage` flags indicating `GRALLOC_USAGE_SW_READ_OFTEN`.

If possible, please enable this flag in `usage` flags prior to the creation of `GraphicBuffer` and retry your experiment, which I feel should be successful.

Comment: You Mean, to enable flag kEnableGrallocUsageProtected ?

Comment: In the usage flags being passed to `gralloc`, you should include `GRALLOC_USAGE_SW_READ_OFTEN`. For example, in case of `kEnableGrallocUsageProtected`, there is an update to usage flags as in http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/OMXCodec.cpp#1848 . One example can be found here: http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/native/libs/gui/tests/SurfaceTextureGL_test.cpp#332

Comment: Hi, I tried this method. No luck. any other suggestion please?